# Return column with the second largest date in the dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple query that returns the dataset and a measure that represents a column with the highest date found.

```
select *, max(date) over () as date_max
from table
```

I need to increment this query and insert a new column that returns the second highest date found (it will still contain that column with the highest date). Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just query for the second largest like

```
select max(date) from table where date < (select max(date) from table)
```

You can use this in a subquery in the main query for example. Alternatively, you can get the max date first, and then use it to get the second largest value, also using a window function like you did, like so:

```
with top1 as 
(
select i, max(i) over () as largest
  from d
)
select i, largest
       -- ignore the largest value when aggregating
     , max(case when i = largest then null else i end) over () as second_largest
  from top1
```

Keep in mind both of them will return the actual second largest value, duplicates excluded (so 100, 100, 99 would return 99 as the second largest).

[live demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=721445838b5126ff27a082d6e1328592)